# JUnit asserting arrays are equal when they're not

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I have a mergesort function I am testing using JUnit.  Below is one of my test cases:

```
@Test
    //test using randomly generated numbers
    public void MergeSortTest002()
    {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random rng = new Random(seed);
        Integer[] TestArray = new Integer[1000];
        int MAX_VALUE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            //this will generate positive and negative numbers from
            // -MAX_VALUE/2 to +MAX_VALUE/2
            Integer newNum = rng.nextInt(MAX_VALUE/2) - MAX_VALUE;
            TestArray[i] = newNum;
        }

        Integer[] correctArray = TestArray;
        Arrays.sort(correctArray);
        MergeSort.mergeSort(TestArray);

        Assert.assertArrayEquals(correctArray,TestArray);
    }
```

The strange thing is, even if I comment out the line where I call my `mergeSort` function, the test still passes.

I figured one of two things is happening: Either `assertArrayEquals` does not care about the order of elements (unlikely), of when I'm copying `TestArray` to `correctArray`, it's copying by reference, and thus calling `Arrays.sort` on `correctArray` is sorting `TestArray` as well.

Could anyone confirm which of the two is happening, and what should be the solution? Is there a `Assert` that keeps order in mind, or is there a way to copy arrays by values rather than reference without writing an explicit for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
Integer[] correctArray = TestArray;
```

You're copying the *reference* to your array, not the *contents* of the array.

To fix, change that line to:

```
Integer[] correctArray = TestArray.clone();
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I figured this was the issue, but had no clue about the existence of `.clone()`.